# How to derive Gödel universe metric?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, time-evolution

I've always really liked the [Gödel universe metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_metric), and I like the parallels with time travel, but I couldn't take advantage of the mathematics of it completely because I don't know where the shape of that metric came from, someone can show an intuitive derivation of the metric from the Gödel universe.

Comment: Step 1: Be Kurt Gödel. Step 2: ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He didn't derive it, he just wrote it down and then showed what properties it had. Sometimes it is called an "ansatz", which is basically just an educated guess that you make and then work backwards to show that your guess was good.

https://doi.org/10.1103/RevModPhys.21.447

Comment: Makes sense, thank you